# A couple of blkio cgroup files are not present in Linux kernel 5

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have a Ubuntu 19.04 VM (kernel 5.0.0), and I found a couple of blkio cgroup files are not present in it:

```
    ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-196:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
    DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
    DISTRIB_RELEASE=19.04
    DISTRIB_CODENAME=disco
    DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 19.04"

    ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-196:~$ uname -an            
    Linux ip-172-31-44-196 5.0.0-1007-aws #7-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 16 15:18:21 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

    ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-196:~$ ls -la /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/
    total 0
    dr-xr-xr-x  2 root root   0 Jun 17 03:17 ./
    drwxr-xr-x 15 root root 380 Jun 17 03:14 ../
    --w-------  1 root root   0 Jun 17 03:17 blkio.reset_stats
    -r--r--r--  1 root root   0 Jun 17 03:17 blkio.throttle.io_service_bytes
    -r--r--r--  1 root root   0 Jun 17 03:17 blkio.throttle.io_service_bytes_recursive
    -r--r--r--  1 root root   0 Jun 17 03:17 blkio.throttle.io_serviced
    -r--r--r--  1 root root   0 Jun 17 03:17 blkio.throttle.io_serviced_recursive
    -rw-r--r--  1 root root   0 Jun 17 03:17 blkio.throttle.read_bps_device
    -rw-r--r--  1 root root   0 Jun 17 03:17 blkio.throttle.read_iops_device
    -rw-r--r--  1 root root   0 Jun 17 03:17 blkio.throttle.write_bps_device
    -rw-r--r--  1 root root   0 Jun 17 03:17 blkio.throttle.write_iops_device
    -rw-r--r--  1 root root   0 Jun 17 03:17 cgroup.clone_children
    -rw-r--r--  1 root root   0 Jun 17 03:17 cgroup.procs
    -r--r--r--  1 root root   0 Jun 17 03:17 cgroup.sane_behavior
    -rw-r--r--  1 root root   0 Jun 17 03:17 notify_on_release
    -rw-r--r--  1 root root   0 Jun 17 03:17 release_agent
    -rw-r--r--  1 root root   0 Jun 17 03:17 tasks
```

In a Ubuntu 18.04 VM, I can see:

```
$ uname -an
Linux workstation 4.15.0-23-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 23 18:02:16 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ ls -la /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio
-r--r--r--  1 root root   0 Jun 14 06:25 blkio.io_merged
-r--r--r--  1 root root   0 Jun 14 06:25 blkio.io_merged_recursive
-r--r--r--  1 root root   0 Jun 14 06:25 blkio.io_queued
-r--r--r--  1 root root   0 Jun 14 06:25 blkio.io_queued_recursive
-r--r--r--  1 root root   0 Jun 14 06:25 blkio.io_service_bytes
-r--r--r--  1 root root   0 Jun 14 06:25 blkio.io_service_bytes_recursive
-r--r--r--  1 root root   0 Jun 14 06:25 blkio.io_serviced
-r--r--r--  1 root root   0 Jun 14 06:25 blkio.io_serviced_recursive
-r--r--r--  1 root root   0 Jun 14 06:25 blkio.io_service_time
-r--r--r--  1 root root   0 Jun 14 06:25 blkio.io_service_time_recursive
-r--r--r--  1 root root   0 Jun 14 06:25 blkio.io_wait_time
-r--r--r--  1 root root   0 Jun 14 06:25 blkio.io_wait_time_recursive
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   0 Jun 14 06:25 blkio.leaf_weight
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   0 Jun 14 06:25 blkio.leaf_weight_device
--w-------  1 root root   0 Jun 14 06:25 blkio.reset_stats
-r--r--r--  1 root root   0 Jun 14 06:25 blkio.sectors
-r--r--r--  1 root root   0 Jun 14 06:25 blkio.sectors_recursive
-r--r--r--  1 root root   0 Jun 14 06:25 blkio.throttle.io_service_bytes
-r--r--r--  1 root root   0 Jun 14 06:25 blkio.throttle.io_serviced
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   0 May 31 16:53 blkio.throttle.read_bps_device
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   0 May 31 16:53 blkio.throttle.write_iops_device
-r--r--r--  1 root root   0 Jun 14 06:25 blkio.time
-r--r--r--  1 root root   0 Jun 14 06:25 blkio.time_recursive
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   0 May 31 16:53 blkio.weight
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   0 May 31 16:53 blkio.weight_device
...
```

So it seems a couple of blkio cgroup files are not present in kernel 5.0, anyone knows why? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and after some investigation I noticed that it's related to [IO Scheduler](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Reference/IOSchedulers).

In my case I could see these files when using *kernel 4.15* and *cfq* scheduler but these files didn't exist when using *kernel 5.5* and *mq-deadline* scheduler. It seems in newer kernel versions some of these files are only exist when using [*bfq* scheduler](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/7ada90eb9c7ae4a8eb066f8e9b4d80122f0363db/block/bfq-cgroup.c#L1281).

You can see your current IO scheduler for *sda* block device using command below:

```
 cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
```

Also you can switch to *bfq* using these commands:

```
sudo modprobe bfq
echo "bfq" | sudo tee /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
```

As you can see in [this code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/7ada90eb9c7ae4a8eb066f8e9b4d80122f0363db/block/bfq-cgroup.c#L1298) these files are being used only when CONFIG_BFQ_CGROUP_DEBUG in kernel options is being enabled, so switching to bfq may not be enough. You can see your current kernel options using below command:

```
less /boot/config-`uname -r`
```

if CONFIG_BFQ_CGROUP_DEBUG is not exist inside config file, you should change this config file and rebuild your kernel. You can use [this instruction](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/GitKernelBuild) for changing kernel config. Just add CONFIG_BFQ_CGROUP_DEBUG=y to config file and rebuild and install kernel.